# Find String Between 2 Strings

Tags: php, strpos

I'm parsing email subjects for specific information.
The function below will return whatever string exists between 2 strings.

```
<?php

function find_string_between_characters($haystack, $starter, $ender) {
  if(empty($haystack)) return '';
  $il = strpos($haystack,$starter,0)+strlen($starter);
  $ir = strpos($haystack,$ender,$il);
  return substr($haystack,$il,($ir-$il));
}

$string = 'Re: [Ticket #6588] Site security update';
$begin = '[Ticket #';
$end = ']';
echo find_string_between_characters($string, $begin, $end); // result: 6588
?>
```

Resulting with: **6588** 
This is exactly what I wanted, of course.
I just barely noticed that if I change the variables like this:

```
<?php
$string = 'New Ticket Email Submitted';
$begin = '[Ticket #';
$end = ']';
echo find_string_between_characters($string, $begin, $end); // result: t Email
?>
```

Resulting with:  **t Email**

How do I adjust the function to look at the exact sequence of characters inside both the **$begin** and **$end** variables?

Comment: a simple preg_match() would be easy

Comment: is the patter is constant i.e. [Ticket #6588] ?

Comment: Yep, luckily pretty constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use preg_match as

```
$input_line = 'Re: [Ticket #6588] Site security update' ;
preg_match("/\[Ticket #(.*?)\]/i", $input_line, $output_array);

echo $output_array[1];


/\[Ticket #(.*?)\]/i

    \[ matches the character [ literally
    Ticket # matches the characters Ticket # literally (case insensitive)
    1st Capturing group (.*?)
        .*? matches any character (except newline)
            Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
    \] matches the character ] literally
    i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'Re: [Ticket #6588] Site security update';
preg_match('/\[Ticket #(.*?)\]/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```